# How to correctly include own libraries in function files and project files

Tags: c, libraries, kernighan-and-ritchie

I got stuck trying to do `Exercise 8-3` of K&R, the goal of the exercise is to rewrite some functions of `stdio.h` such as `fopen`, `fclose`, `fillbuf` and `flushbuf`
here's how my source files are organized:

`stdio.h`: contains types and macro definitions, and the declarations of some functions proper to the library. all content of the file is enclosed between `#ifndef` `#endif` lines as follows:

```
#ifndef STDIO_H
#define STDIO_H
/* content of stdio.h */
#endif
```

`myfunction.c`: I have a `.c` file per function, each file has a `#include "stdio.h"` line to load all needed types definitions.

`main.c`: where I have code to test my functions, the `main.c` also has a `#include "stdio.h"` line.

**my problem is the following:** when I try to compile all my files using `gcc` I run to the error:

```
multiple definition of `_iob'
```

on every one of my function files where my `stdio.h` is included, (`_iob` is a variable I only defined inside my `stdio.h`)...why is this happening ? I though the `#ifndef` line was to specifically  prevent such errors.

**more generally:**

1. How would you go about making your own header files and library/function files and using them in your projects ?
2. Is there a way to make the linker figure out the position of my functions just by including the header file, the same way it does for standard functions ?

Comment: Is that the only warning or error you get? Do you have sufficient warnings enabled? (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc, `/W3` for VS (`cl.exe`) or `-Weverything` for clang)? I would certainly change the name of "my `stdio.h`" to something NOT `stdio.h`, e.g. `my_stdio.h`. (if you did in fact name your header `stdio.h`)

Comment: Hello, yes that is the only error I have (run with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please become aware of the difference between a [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) and its [header files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive).

A library is a (collection of) binary [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) (with some additional meta-data, e.g. [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) directives to the linker).

For example, on my Linux system, dynamic libraries are generally shared objects (e.g. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so`) and it makes absolutely no sense to try some preprocessor directive like `#include "libgmp.so" //wrong`.

But a library has some [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). That API is given by some documentation and by some header file(s), e.g. `gmp.h` and you should `#include "gmp.h"` in any C code (your C translation unit) which uses it.

> myfunction.c: I have a .c file per function

Having one file per function is often poor taste. You generally can group related functions. For example, in your case, you probably want to define your `myfopen` and `myfclose` functions in the same `myopenclose.c` translation unit (even if you don't have to) because these two functions are intimately related. As a rule of thumb, I prefer having source files of one or a few thousand lines each (but that is really a matter of taste, and some people like having many small files).

Remember that what the compiler really sees is the preprocessed form of code. Consider asking your compiler to produce that form (e.g. from `foo.c`  you can  get its preprocessed form `foo.i`  with `gcc -C -E -Wall foo.c > foo.i` on my Linux desktop) and look into it. Try that on your own files (e.g. your `myopenclose.c` if you have one).

If you have many small files, the compiler is probably including the same headers in each of them, and these included declarations gets compiled every time. BTW, notice that `gcc` is only a driver program. Use it with `-v` flag. You'll see that it is running `cc1` (the  C compiler proper), `as` (the assembler), `ld` (the linker), etc.

> I run to the error:
>
> multiple definition of `_iob'
>
> on every one of my function files where my stdio.h is included, (`_iob` is a variable I only defined inside my stdio.h).

You probably should *declare* `extern` your  `_iob`  global variable in your `stdio.h` and *define* a global `_iob` in only one implementation file (perhaps `myopenclose.c`, if it is relevant) of your library.

Don't confuse *definition* and *declaration* (of variables, functions, types, etc.). Spend some time reading the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). These words are defined there. As a rule of thumb, declarations should go into header `.h` files, definitions (of variables and functions) in implementation `.c` files (of course details are much more complex, you often but not always define types and `struct` in header files).

I strongly recommend using some Linux distribution (it is very developer- and student- friendly) and *studying* the source code of some *existing* free software [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (like [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/), whose code is quite readable). More generally, study the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)). They will inspire you.

> Is there a way to make the linker figure out the position of my functions just by including the header file, the same way it does for standard functions ?

This shows a lot of confusion (the above question does not make any sense). Read more about [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (your  `cc1` program -started by `gcc`-  is translating a `.c` file into some [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) `.o`) and about [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) (your `ld`, generally started by `gcc`, is agglomerating several object files, processing relocations inside them, and producing an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) library or an executable). The [preprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (e.g. of `#include` directive) is done at compile time by `cc1`. The linker cannot see any header files (it only deals with object files or libraries).

Comment: thank you for the answer, I've modified the last portion of my question following your remarks. how would I include the needed definitions in my `.c` files though ? should I just include the `.h` file in each one of them ? that's the source of my compilation error (multiple definitions of variables in my `.h`file that was included in all my `.c` files)? and do you know why my `#ifndef` isn't preventing that ?

Comment: You are confused (at several levels). Please get the preprocessed form of your code and study it with a pager or editor.

Comment: The preprocessed form of my code ? how would I do that ? I am pretty confused alright :) ... would you link me to some reading material so I can better understand ?

Comment: I gave a  command ending with `> foo.i`. Adapt that command for your file. Look into your equivalent `.i` file with an editor.

Comment: Thank you for the kind advice. (I am running Linux by the way) I think you got it, I am already declaring `_iob` as `extern` in my `stdio.h` file, what I am doing wrong is also defining it in the same file, so it gets declared every time `stdio.h` is included...

Comment: Don't confuse "definition" and "declaration" of variable. You are using the wrong words in the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite some of the system declarations and functions, while at the same time including the system declarations, you can expect some collisions.

Header files (.h) contain code (usually only declarations) and the mechanism you describe (`#ifndef STDIO_H`) is to prevent multiple inclusions of the same header file - mainly because another include file (header) that has already been loaded might also include it. That result in the same kind of collision as you had.

In C, you could, for instance

- make a new header file that contain your own declarations + the stdio ones that don't collide with yours
- use the stdio declarations, and only write new functions that use the same structures, defines, enums etc... as stdio
- rewrite the necessary declarations and code that allows you *not* to include the system headers anymore
- use another naming convention, like `my_iob` in both your header file, and in your code.

The two last ones are probably the best in your case, since you still have some collisions coming from a header file.

For instance, your code might not include `stdio.h`, but another header file you include might do it, indirectly...

Comment: Hello, I am not including the standard `stdio.h` anywhere in my code